# how to replace location.href link using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have lots of page with button. I want to replace some specific links with another link.
Here is the HTML code

```
<button onclick="changeURL()">change link</button>
<button onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" id="link">go to link</button>
```

I tried to add this script but it's not working.

```
<script>
   function changeURL(){
        var newURL = "https://youtube.com";
        document.getElementById("link").href = newURL;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a button on "_lots of_" pages or "_lots of_" buttons on a page? How are you handling different URLs for different buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This is [good code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href).

Perhaps `getElementById(link)` does not exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem i see is that you try to change the value of href, but the Button dont supports hrefs.

try this:

```js
function changeURL() {
  var newURL = "https://youtube.com";
  document.getElementById("link").onclick = window.location.href = newURL;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeURL()">change link</button>
<button onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" id="link">go to link</button>
```

If you have many buttons with different ids you can wrote the name in your function, like this:

```js
function changeURL(link) {
  var newURL = "https://youtube.com";
  document.getElementById(link).onclick = window.location.href = newURL;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeURL('link1')">change link</button>
<button onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" id="link1">go to link</button>
```

Comment: This function will only work for a single button

Comment: But the Button have an ID, its not possible to have more as one Button with the same id. Or are the buttons have different ids?

Answer (score 0):

If there are lots of buttons on a page that need to have their intended target modified perhaps the following will  be of interest. You cannot have duplicate ID attributes and expect any Javascript code that uses the ID to behave correctly. You **could** modify that ID and make it a `dataset` property, such as `data-id='link'` and that is perfectly valid and makes sense when trying to identify more than one element as shown below.

The button that is used to change the target of the buttons calls `document.querySelectorAll` to identify any/all buttons with the `data-id` property and then iterates through that nodelist to modify the event handler assigned to each button.

I added the `data-name` attribute only to indicate different buttons - it plays no part in the modification code

```js
const _url_='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';

const go_to_youtube=(evt)=>{
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log( 'Navigating to: %s', _url_ );
  return document.location.href=_url_;
}

document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.type=='change' ){
    document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id="link"]').forEach(n=>{
      n.addEventListener('click', go_to_youtube );
    })
  }
});
```

```css
div > button{display:block}
button{margin:0.25rem;padding:0.25rem}
button[data-id='link']:after{margin:0 0 0 0.25rem;color:red;content:attr(data-name)}
```

```html
<button data-type='change'>Change links</button>
<div>
  <button data-name='google' onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" data-id="link">go to link</button>
  <button data-name='yahoo' onclick="location.href='https://yahoo.com'" data-id="link">go to link</button>
  <button data-name='askjeeves' onclick="location.href='https://askjeeves.com'" data-id="link">go to link</button>
  <button data-name='microsoft' onclick="location.href='https://microsoft.com'" data-id="link">go to link</button>
  <button data-name='facebook' onclick="location.href='https://facebook.com'" data-id="link">go to link</button>
  <button data-name='tiktok' onclick="location.href='https://tiktok.com'" data-id="link">go to link</button>
  <button data-name='example' onclick="location.href='https://example.com'" data-id="link">go to link</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `function` as a value to `onclick` and inside that function assign the correct value to `newURL`.

```js
   function changeURL(){
        var newURL = "https://youtube.com";
        document.getElementById("link").onclick = function() {
            location.href = newURL;
        };
        console.log(document.getElementById("link").onclick);
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="changeURL()">change link</button>
<button onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" id="link">go to link</button>
```